# I think someone is remotely viewing my laptop; how can I stop it?

Tags: windows, remote-access

My laptop was a gift from my ex-boyfriend, who spent years studying studying network security, VPNs, partitions, and **remote admin/access**. Upon dumping me last week, he said:

```
I'll be watching you.
```

I opened a `cmd` window and entered `netstat -ano`. The window filled with 24 TCP ports --listening and established -- and 4 UDP ports that don't list "State" (but appear to be local addresses). Also, there are lots of different PIDs and foreign, as well as local addresses. I interpret this to mean that there's some sort of remote access software on my computer.

I'm not convinced my problems are the result of web surfing. I'm pretty well shielded by my antimalware solution, and never traverse a WiFi connection without HotSpot Shield or what not.

How do I get these gremlins out?

Comment: Stop browsing the Web.

Comment: Use a proper firewall configuration allowing only trusted apps.

Comment: Given the way most people rattle on and on on social media, @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams pretty much nails it on the head. You don't need to install anything to watch people anymore, they more or less do it to themselves.

Comment: Nuke it from orbit. It is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, if any sort of Windows Networking and other usual twiddlefidget people stick on their machine is running, it's kind of meh as to what's described and doesn't really tell us if anything's been tampered with.

If he wasn't just doing mind games on you and actually used a competent remote access trojan, it will do a good job of disguising itself and you don't weed it out.

Under these circumstances, you back up all your user data and scrub it for any executable programs.

You then nuke from your laptop orbit -> scrub the disk clean with DBAN or similar and reinstall the operating system and any programs you found useful from their original install media.

Otherwise there's no way of knowing if you've done anything more than chase your tail trying to remove the unremovable.

Answer (score 0):

There is malicious software ("malware") which allows such remote spying. On the other hand, a lot of applications are using network connections and it takes some reading to find out what is ok and what is suspicious.

The tool [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) is helpful to get an overview of the current connections. Stop all your own programs and shutdown background services like Skype to keep the list short.

Keep your anti-virus software updated. In doubt, you should cover your web cam with a bit of black sticky tape.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in doubt, I suggest to backup your files and settings and then wipe the machine (as in format the hard disk) and perform a clean install (using a recovery disc etc.)

You might spend hours on end trying to find 'the spy' but will never be sure you got 'him' or there is none.

If you do a clean-install you have a least the assurance that *you* controlled how it was set-up.

In case you want to keep the system state you can make an image (raw level) before you wipe it. You could then run the image in a VM to further tinker with it.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly cromulent answer

Comment: @Mawg had to look 'cromulent' up but thanks for your comment :-)

Comment: Lolx! I don't blame you for not knowing it, the Simpsons [jumped the shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_the_shark) long ago; Family Guy is the only thing watching these days (apart, of course, from the incomparable Cleveland Show).  Thanks for the upvote. "A noble upvote [embiggens](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/newsbeat-43298229) the smallest man"